# Why is port 500 in use and how can I free it? VPNC error

Tags: networking, vpn, ubuntu-10.10, cisco-vpn-client, vpnc

I tried to use [NetworkManager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetworkManager) to connect to my university's VPN, but it didn't work.
Then I used a command line vpnc:

```
> sudo vpnc
[sudo] password for kirill: 
Enter IPSec gateway address: vpn.net.**.edu
Enter IPSec ID for vpn.net.**.edu: **
Enter IPSec secret for **@vpn.net.**.edu: 
Enter username for vpn.net.**.edu: **
Enter password for **@vpn.net.**.edu: 
vpnc: Error binding to source port. Try '--local-port 0'
Failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:500: Address already in use
```

Then I did

> sudo vpnc --local-port 0

with the same configuration, and it all worked.

I'd like to be able to use the NetworkManager GUI to connect to VPN. I wanted to find out which program uses port 500:

```
> sudo netstat -a |grep 500
tcp        0      0 *:17500                 *:*                     LISTEN     
udp        0      0 *:4500                  *:*                                
udp        0      0 *:17500                 *:*                                
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     63500    
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     12500    @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

There is nothing that uses 50.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 on a [ThinkPad X201](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_tablet_computers#Convertible_tablets).

Answer (score 1):

UDP port 500 is used by ISAKMP, the IPsec key exchange protocol.

If `netstat` does not list the port as in use, try `vpnc` again after waiting a minute or so.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me;

in my case reason was another vpn client installed (Shrew Soft Ike) and auto-starting at start-up.

Try to catch if some other vpn client is running (in my case, ps -e | grep ike), kill it and configure it to start only when required.